# Get row position in the result?

Tags: mysql, sql

How use @row_number like position row in result in this SQL:

```
SELECT s.*, 
s2.priority AS `priority`, 
@row_number := @row_number := @row_number + 1  AS `top`

FROM (SELECT @row_number := 0) init, `server` s
        LEFT JOIN servers_services ss ON (s.id = ss.server_id)
        LEFT JOIN service s2 ON (s2.id = ss.service_id)
WHERE s.is_banned = 0

ORDER BY ss.service_id IS NULL, priority DESC
```

@row_number takes values {1, 12, 89 ...} Why?

Comment: `@row_number := @row_number := @row_number + 1` > `@row_number := @row_number + 1`

Comment: @RubahMalam, your example printed "0" as a top

Comment: Actually, your query should works, unless you have another longer query than this.

Comment: This query works, but field `top` is not correct because i want gets 0,1,2,3,4 values, not 1, 12, 89....
This all query , no more...

Comment: Can you provide your table in http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16df2/1/0

Comment: Can you also provide the sample data? Because it's hard to check without data sample.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with variables in MySQL, so my anser can be wrong.

My guess is: You cross join row numbers with your tables. Then in the WHERE clause you dismiss records, so you are left with only some of the original row numbers.

As to how to solve this, I imagine not to join the undesired records in the first place should help:

```
FROM (SELECT @row_number := 0) init
JOIN server s ON s.is_banned = 0
LEFT JOIN servers_services ss ON (s.id = ss.server_id)
LEFT JOIN service s2 ON (s2.id = ss.service_id)
```